# Enter passphrase for key

Tags: for-loop, key, enter, passphrase

I am trying to clone a heroku app with a folder in my pc.I used the git clone command to do the cloning.
It is asking for passphrase for key, like below.What should, I enter for this?

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/users/<my-name>/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Macintosh you look in your Keychain for "SSH" and you should see your id_rsa passphrase. It's a password you created long ago when you set up your coding environment. I don't know where PC's secure passwords. See https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/

Answer (score -3):

Enter the password of your github account.

Comment: I have not tried this, but I have deleted the id_rsa file and created ssh keys once again, and when I tried to use it, it did not ask for th e passphrase.

Comment: It's not asking for his GitHub password, it's asking for his SSH id_rsa passphrase. This is a passphrase that he created when he set up SSH.